# Andorid debug apk not working on another phone

Tags: android, button, installation, apk, galaxy

I have developed an android app which uses google maps api v2. I usb-debuged and run the app on Nexus 5 with no problem. Now I want to test the app on Galaxy S3. I installed the app using debug apk on galaxy and when it runs, it does not allow me to click on some buttons. It drives me crazy because I could not find any reason for that. So I found another galaxy s3 and installed the apk but this time the app is not even started. It says app is stopped. Could anyone give me some ideas about these problems?

Note: I already checked the min android version in the manifest file.

Thanks.

Comment: i think your generated apk is not signed .http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more information about why it is crashing activate the developer mode and the usb debug mode in the settings and then check the logs.